# disable touch and move events for image view in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm implementing animation for images in my android app. Want to disable touch or moving image with fingers by users. User can navigate to next image by clicking next/previous buttons.

Kindly help me how I can disable touch or moving image manually by users programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -(vWidth-aWidth),0.0f, 0.0f);
                                        animation.setDuration(7000);
                                    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                                    animation.setRepeatMode(2);
                                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

fullImageView.startAnimation(animation);

Here, vWidth is double the aWidth.

This will animate image on screen. User can see this animation but they should not drag the image to see full width.

Please check and help me.

Comment: How do you move your image, how do you use touch events? Add that code

Comment: Yeah it sound sreally strange because as long as you dont do anything in code your views do not respond to touchevents lol